# Htaccess mod_rewrite blocking my css

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Got htaccess rewriting my links for better seo like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .*/([^/]+)/?     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php      [NC]
RewriteRule  .*      /index.php?cat=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

which rewrites

```
http://www.example.com/any/number/of/directories/lastDir
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?cat=lastDir
```

but my css isnt working, when i upload htaccess to the server, there is just plain text without images and css

tried adding base tag into html, but its not working

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

Comment: Try using `.*/([^/.]+)/?` instead. Your rule is probably matching the css and image file. Don't allowing dots in the rewrite would prevent this, since the file-extension contains a dot.

Comment: not working for example.com/aaaa, only working for example.com/aaa/bbb and so on

Answer (score 2):

You must exclude the css and images from being rewritten with a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: +1 for `jpe?g`, never thought of that before, i always use `jpeg|jpg` and have been racking my brains for something neater and cleaner

Comment: @bizzehdee Thank you, I adopted it from somewhere else. Nothing wrong with `jpeg|jpg`, though.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .*/([^/]+)/?     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img|font|js|css|scripts) [NC]
RewriteRule  .*      /index.php?cat=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

this will filter out certain file types and directories to make sure that assets are not redirected

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem as well and found a solution.

If your css / js files are linked with a relative path, your RewriteRule will also affect them. Instead of writing a RewriteCond, you can avoid this by using a path from the root directory. In other words:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

becomes

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Where `css` is a directory in the root directory.