# Basic URL rewriting: How to have a css link, img src, etc, ignore it?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website running at `localhost/pm` and the RewriteBase is correctly set to `/pm/`. There is a link tag in my document: `<link ... href="themes/default/css/default.css">`.

When the url is `localhost/pm` or `localhost/pm/foo` the CSS works all right. When there are more slashes in the URL, however, like `localhost/pm/foo/bar` the relative URL if the stylesheet changes to `foo/themes/default/css/default.css`.

How do I get this to work without having to put some sort of PHP path resolution in the link tag?

```
# invoke rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pm/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

EDIT:

Basically what I need now is this:
If request contains folder name `/themes/` scrap everything that is before `/themes/` and rewrite the rest to `/pm/themes/...`

I tried it like this: `RewriteRule ^.*(/themes/.*)$ /pm/themes/$1` but I get an internal server error. Why?

If I do it like this: `RewriteRule ^.*(/themes/.*)$ /pm/themes/` (ie. just remove $1 from the end) and use the URL `http://localhost/pm/foo/themes/foo/` the resulting physical location is `http://localhost/pm/themes` which is what is expected too, which in turn means that at least my regex is correct. What am I missing?

Comment: You must exclude the css from being rewritten with a RewriteCond, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15348786/1741542 or rewrite CSS requests as well, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535329/1741542

Comment: Didn't help. Using a <base> tag did, however.

Comment: Be careful, when using the `base` tag, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1889076/1741542 for details. If your css files are located below `/pm/themes/default/css/`, you can rewrite these as well.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Ouch, the anchor issue is a bad thing. Any ideas why the solution in your first comment does not work for me? Could it be a server config issue?

Comment: According to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3701958/1383913 my problem can't be solved with so far suggested measures. I have elaborated my question further, please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RewriteRule is almost correct

```
RewriteRule ^.*(/themes/.*)$ /pm/themes/$1
```

This rewrites `http://localhost/pm/foo/themes/default/css/default.css` to `http://localhost/pm/themes/themes/default/css/default.css`, which is one `themes` too much. Use this instead

```
RewriteRule /themes/(.*)$ /pm/themes/$1 [L]
```

But now you have an endless rewrite loop, because `/pm/themes/..` is rewritten again and again. To prevent this, you need a `RewriteCond` excluding `/pm/themes`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pm/themes/
RewriteRule /themes/(.*)$ /pm/themes/$1 [L]
```

Now the request is rewritten only once and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the following lines before your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It will only evaluate your rewrite rule if the requested file or directory doesn't exist.

You should post your `.htaccess` file so we can offer better advice